# bash: while loop going to infinite loop while case statement

Tags: linux, bash

This is my below bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
verify()
{
  while true ;do
      read -p "Have you fixed  ? Yes/No: " yn
      case $yn in
         YES|Yes|yes|y|Y)
         printf "Hola"
         check_status
         break
         #continue
         ;;
         NO|No|no|n|N)
         printf "Please fix"
         ;;
         *)
         printf "Please answer yes or no.\n"
         ;;
     esac
  done
}

check_status()
{
  while IFS=" " read -r rec1 rec2
  do
  if [ $rec2 == 'up' ]
  then
    echo "$rec1 is up"
  else
    echo "$rec1 is down so please fix"
    verify
  fi
  done < <(cut -d " " -f1,2 compute_list)
}


check_status
```

and my compute list is

```
abcd up
efgh down
..
```

And it is always giving

It is not showing the line

Have you fixed  ? Yes/No:

But it is showing the below infinetely

***Please answer yes or No?
Please answer yes or No?***

infinite loop it is showing same messages again and again and again

Any help

Comment: The input to `read` builtin in `verify` function is redirected to the
output of `cut` in `check_status` function rather than the user's console input.Try to say `read -p "Have you fixed  ? Yes/No: " yn < /dev/tty` in `verify`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outer function has redirected standard input to read from the `cut` process substitution, so that's where `read` is reading its input from.

Perhaps use a separate file descriptor for the process substitution.

Furthermore, your `verify` function recursively calls `check_status` again; probably take that out!

```
verify()
{
  while true ;do
      read -p "Have you fixed? Yes/No: " yn
      case $yn in
        YES|Yes|yes|y|Y)
         echo "Hola"
         # check_status # DON'T!
         break
         ;;
        NO|No|no|n|N)
         echo "Please fix"
         ;;
        *)
         echo "Please answer yes or no."
         ;;
     esac
  done
}
 
check_status()
{
  # Notice read -u 3 to read from fd3
  # Notice _ to read fields 3 and up
  while IFS=" " read -u 3 -r rec1 rec2 _
  do
    # Syntax: single =, add quoting
    if [ "$rec2" = 'up' ]
    then
      echo "$rec1 is up"
    else
      echo "$rec1 is down so please fix"
      verify
    fi
  # Notice 3<
  done 3< compute_list
}
 
check_status
```

I also took the liberty to fix your indentation and avoid the unnecessary process substitution; `read` can perfectly well read and discard the fields after the second.

`printf` is more versatile than `echo` but in this case, when you simply want to output static strings, I switched to `echo`.

Demo: https://ideone.com/pVerFm
(I left in the process substitution there in case you want to see what it looks like syntactically.)